# How to make sure the table caption is on the same page as the table?

Tags: php, css, css-selectors, dompdf

I have multiple tables with caption getting generated in PHP and redendered using dompdf.  I don't know the length of the tables or how many there will be before generating the PDF.

Right now in some case the table caption is at the end of a page and the table start on the next page.

How can I make sure they are both on the same page but whitout forcing a page break on all new table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `page-break-inside: avoid;` on the table to avoid the whole table to be split, or `page-break-after: avoid` on the first table row (containing the `th` elements) to avoid a page break directly after it.

To apply that to multiple tables at once you could use the selector `table tr:first-of-type` for that rule.

Comment: According to the owner of dompdf, the table caption is not well supported right now.  I think I may have managed to have the caption to stick with the headers using `page-break-after: avoid` on the caption , but now in my test case I have a page where the caption and table header are on one page and the data on another.